# （C++) How to call a variable name or get the value of a variable in different cpp files?

Tags: c++

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eivu7.png)

if I want to call use the value of char slide_piece in another cpp file. How do i implement the header file and how to call the function? Thanks

Comment: If you can edit GameLogic.cpp and GameLogic.h then it's doable but its a lot of hassle. Perhaps there is something else that can be done https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: copy and paste your code here as text, not in an image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GameLogic` is a class and `slide_piece` should be a member of it. Than you have to add a getter function:

```
// GameLogic.h 

class GameLogic
{
public:
    char get_slide_piece() // getter function
    {
        return m_slide_piece;
    }

    // The rest of the class:
    
    bool MouseDown( char file, char rank, wxPoint &point ); // Sets m_slide_piece value

    // & more

protected:
    char m_slide_piece = '\0';
            // I use to add to member-variable names: "m_" 
            // So I suggest to rename it to m_slide_piece
            // to make it easier to realize when you read the
            // code in the cpp that it is a member-variable.

    // The rest of the class
};
```

In the other cpp file, access it by:

```
char slide_piece = game_logic.get_slide_piece(); // game_logic is a GameLogic object
```

In your example, `slide_piece` is a variable of `MouseDown` function and it is not valid after the function returned. The use of global variables is not a good practice.

Comment: While other have mentioned ways to do it with global approaches, I think this is the most OOP like approach, and probably what OP should go for.

Comment: Thanks so much, it resolved my need so well.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with C++17, you can declare and define your constant in a header using `inline`:

```
inline constexpr char slide_piece = '\42';
```

Which is the easiest and cleanest solution for that problem IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Declare it in header file as extern:

MyHeader.h:

```
extern char slide_piece;
```

Define it in Source file: (including MyHeader.h is not necessary, but it's good practice)

MySource.cpp:

```
#include "MyHeader.h"

char slide_piece;
```

Use it in any other source by including the header:

OtherSource.cpp:

```
#include "MyHeader.h"

// slide_piece is available here
```